# 'MissingRequiredArgument' object has no attribute 'send' - discord.py rewrite

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a script that detects when a 'MissingRequiredArgument' error occurs on a command and sends a message to inform the user. It worked fine till yesterday, when this error showed up:

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'MissingRequiredArgument' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I don't know what happend!
Also, this is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Missing argument(s)!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works for you

```py
    async def on_command_error(ctx, exception):
        error = getattr(exception, "original", exception)

        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send("Missing argument(s)!")
            return
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this one instead

```
 #     await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Missing Arguments')      #
```

or try replacing:
#    'send' with 'send_message'     #